# spring security native xss filter

Tags: spring-security, xss

Why Spring Security doesn't provide any XSS filter to clean the form input values?

Accordingly to this ticket, such XSS filter is a low priority:
https://jira.spring.io/browse/SEC-2167?jql=text%20~%20%22xss%22

(although the ticket speaks only about URL querystring. Sanitizing POST params would be also required)

In my opinion it would be really useful that spring would provide such a filter instead of building your own. This filter it's a recurrent problem.

Comment: If you insert any user entered data into an HTML page without properly escaping it, you have a security problem and innocent text like "C&A" won't work.  If you properly escape it, you don't need an XSS filter.

Comment: But this is something spring could handle so that the programmer don't have to care about escaping. Benefits: 1) you don't have to refactor legacy applications 2) you don't have to care about escaping 3) you may prefer to clean instead of escape

Answer (score 2):

XSS is best handled at output stage via the use of encoding. That is, store everything in your database as is, and yes storing `<script>` is fine, however once output, encode correctly for the context it is output in. For HTML this would be `&lt;script&gt;`, however if your output context was plain text you would just output as is `<script>` (assuming the same character set encoding is used). *Side note: Use parameterised queries or equivalent for storing in your database to avoid SQL injection, however the text stored should exactly match what was entered.*

Microsoft attempts to block inputs that look like XSS via their request validation feature in ASP.NET. However, this isn't very effective and [flaws](https://web.nvd.nist.gov/view/vuln/detail?vulnId=CVE-2008-3842) are [found](https://web.nvd.nist.gov/view/vuln/detail?vulnId=CVE-2008-3843) quite often. Similar approaches from other frameworks are doomed to fail.

The reason that this is much better is that it makes things much more simple. Imagine if StackOverflow didn't allow HTML or script tags - the site would not be functional as a place for people to post code snippets.

You *can* use input validation as second line of defence. For example, if you are asking the user to enter their car registration you would only want to allow alphanumerics and space to be entered. However, for more complex fields it is often difficult to restrict input to a safe set as output context is unknown at this stage.

Say your language filtered `<` and `>` characters. However you were outputting user input into the following context.

```
<img src="foo.jpg" alt="USER-INPUT" />
```

An XSS attack is possible by entering `" onmouseover="alert('xss')` because it would be rendered as

```
<img src="foo.jpg" alt="" onmouseover="alert('xss')" />
```

Similar problems would ensue if you were outputting to JavaScript server-side. This is why it should be up to the developer to select the correct encoding type when using user controlled values.

Comment: I agree that there are situations such the html editor or event handlers such as the one you put that need special care, but in general a native input filter I still think it would be useful. I liked also your comment about field restrictions, made me think that validating fields with annotations can be another way to filter xss

Comment: A native input filter also does not guard against output from other sources - e.g. a database populated via another application. I think native filters tend to hide the problem from developers and cause problems for otherwise valid input (e.g. the .NET one can sometimes block `<` characters entered, creating bugs). If developers are aware of XSS, and that they should be handling it at output stage I think that would be a better way of solving it.